# Managing 100s of similar databases

Tags: mysql, sharding

We are migrating to a model where every "customer" lives in its own dedicated schema (database per tenant). This will allow us to later move some accounts to different DB clusters or upgrade specific accounts to newer schemas, for example. However from the get-go we need to automate how databases are managed in bulk or the whole effort will end up in smoke.

---

**Additional info**: the split is dictated by regulatory reasons and to scale out.

The number of schemas would be about 1000 (today), hosted in ~10 MySQL instances, so roughly 100 schemas per DB instance. New accounts would grow the system at a rate of 100 schemas-per-DB-instance.

My goal is to apply DevOps practices to database change management. So the schema lives in a git repo. Next, we need to be able to selectively or in bulk upgrade specific accounts to bring them to certain "schema version" that's in git.

Problem is figuring out what changes to apply to what databases, sort of like a `diff` and `make` CLI tools but for the database schemas.

I was thinking of creating a file per one of two database objects: a **table** and a **stored procedure**. Fortunately these are the only objects I need to track. Each object in the database has a corresponding file in the git. So if I change a definition in the file, I can run a "db-diff" (a tool I'd create) to tell which objects in what databases are outdated.

To bring the DB schema in sync with the git version of the same object would work something like this:

- for stored procedures that's easy: DROP/CREATE; I'd utilize the SP's `routine_comment` field in the `information_schema.routines` to put there its current git tag. If the version there is outdated, replace it with the SP in the file in git.
- for table objects, it is not clear to me how to compare what's in git vs in DB. One major annoyance of MySQL is that the `show create..` result doesn't show exactly the definition that you asked for in ALTER/CREATE. For example, if you have a `bigint` column, you end up with the silly `bigint(20)`. To a diff tool that's a different schema than what we have in the git.

Is this something I'd need to write myself from scratch or anything already on the market that you recommend?

Comment: Might be a good reason for this databse design, but if its not, maybe you should look into transforing this into a "one databse, multiple customers" solution.

Comment: The reason isn't just "good" - I could fight that one - it's mandated by the regulations.

Comment: You have tagged it with "NDB Cluster".  Perhaps you meant "sharding"?

Comment: Don't be rigid about 100 per shard.  You might get some very busy customers on one shard while having idle or defunct customers on another.

Comment: The distribution of accounts to instances can be by hash, customer "size" or load. The nice thing about schema-per-account is that reallocation is possible. So a few busy customers can be assigned to an instance with much fewer co-located customers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a client with that has 11000 databases with each database containing 90-100 databases each.

This causes several problems:

1. It bloats the INFORMATION_SCHEMA badly. Memory takes a hit.

   - `Apr 22, 2014` : [Do Inactive MySQL Databases Consume Memory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63621/do-inactive-mysql-databases-consume-memory/63650#63650)
   - `Apr 21, 2014` : [Adding new tables -- memory usage increases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63591/adding-new-tables-memory-usage-increases/63593#63593)
   - `Jun 15, 2011` : [How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336)
2. If you ever have to backup a database, it takes 3+ hours for Xtrabackup to read the entire instance's table and column info before it actually starts copying data.
3. Poor performance in one tenant database can hurt performance for the entire instance
4. Maintenance for one tenant database can hurt availability for the entire instance

Please see my old post : [One Big Database vs. Several Smaller Ones](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/one-big-database-vs-several-smaller-ones/7930#7930). It compares a multitenant database to a multitenant building. Ask any landlord of a multitenant building and you will get the same sob story.

## BACK TO REALITY

Managing a building with three tenants is better that managing a complex with 100+ units (NYCHA).

In terms of databases, you should shard the tenants into several independent clusters so that each DB instance holds a decent amount of data without gorging on RAM. Just keep in mind that the more tenant database you have, the more memory will be consumed. (BUYER BEWARE)

Comment: More info added based on your feedback. THANKS!

Comment: Typo:  a 'database' cannot contain 'databases'.  Maybe the second one should be 'tables'?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA we currently have 9 mysql databases; Four are older versions of our software .Five of them should have an identical schema - any differences exist because we did not sync the schema changes yet.  What toold would you recommend to sync schema between quallity insurance stage (QA) and production stage and also to compare all production database to the QA-stage?